# How to make footer responsive through CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make footer responsive through CSS. I've tried it through `background-size: cover` but it's not working. How can i make it responsive?

Here's the CSS code:

```
#super-footer {

    width: 75%; position: relative;
    background-color:#176ca5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 250px;
    height:auto; min-height:200px;
    margin:25px 0 10px 0;
    float:left; 
    background-image:url('images/footer-bg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 25px 30px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         2px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here the link to site:

http://demo.nextsyntax.com/goldcoast/

Comment: When you say "responsive", what do you mean exactly? What should it "respond" to? End of the world?

Comment: Instead of showing the "Gold Coast Point" logo as background, how about adding <img> element as a child of `#super-footer` and set the image width in percentage?

Comment: `I want to make the { background-image:url('images/footer-bg.png'); } scale as per browser window. – MOZ` Maybe if u put the logo just as img and float it to left, it will be ok? Or u want it to be resized? Then u can just add new div with the width in % and background of the logo. Btw I think the site is quite nice when in normal resolution.. but when getting small it\s kinda getting weird the header etc.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can make a responsive design by modifying your css for different resolutions. But there is a library available which is quite good to implement a responsive design.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

It can be used to make your site responsive to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@media` queries

For example

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
#super-footer {
width: 75%;
position: relative;
etc...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it, though i tried media queries earlier and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
<footer class="responsive-footer">

            <div class="footer-left">

                <p class="footer-links">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    |
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>

                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-center">
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                      <p><span>Address</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <p>+00 00-0000000</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    <p><a href="mailto:support@support.com">support@support.com</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">

                <div class="footer-icons">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

```
@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .responsive-footer .footer-left,
    .responsive-footer .footer-center,
    .responsive-footer .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .responsive-footer .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
 ``
```

Comment: Hi Sami. Please consider adding an explanation.